Generating character ranges in python
I want to "translate" integer values in the range from 0 to 26 to characters 'A' to 'Z', but that seems harder in python than in C++, where it is allowed to add integer values to char variables.
The other attempt to generate an array with consecutive characters from a range is apparently also not possible;
I know that I could create an "ABC...XYZ" string for that purpose, but I don't want to do that.
Question.
how can character-ranges à la
ABC = [c for c in range('A','Z')]+['Z']

be generated, resp. emulated in python?

I really dislike closing a question as a duplicate, when you can only know it's a duplicate once you already know the answer.

@MarkRansom The answer may be the same, but the question is different, therefore I leave it up to the philosophers whether we have a duplicate or not...

Python has a pair of functions ord and chr for converting between a character and an integer.  So you can use the regular range function with integers.
ABC = [chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)]


Although in this case and maybe most real cases it might be better to import it from string...
